# Converting long epoch timestamp into date time in PySpark

Tags: python, datetime, pyspark, epoch

I have a spark dataframe with the following schema:

```
root
 |-- var1: long (nullable = true)
 |-- var2: long (nullable = true)
 |-- var3: long (nullable = true)
 |-- y_timestamp: long (nullable = true)
 |-- x_timestamp: long (nullable = true)
```

How do I convert the timestamps into a readable date time variable?

It currently looks like: `1561360513087`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using withColumn when creating the dataframe, you can convert the timestamp (in milliseconds) to seconds, and then convert it to a timestamp.

```
.withColumn("x_timestamp", spark_fns.expr("from_unixtime(x_timestamp/1000, 'yyyy-MM-dd')")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can first convert your Unix timestamps into seconds, and then convert it to a datetime by casting to Spark timestamp (yes, the naming is a bit confusing in Spark - timestamp means datetime)

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.withColumn("var1_timestamp", (F.col("var1")/1000).cast("timestamp"))
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert a timestamp to datetime, you can do:

```py
import datetime

timestamp = 1545730073
dt_object = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
```

but currently your timestamp value is too big: you are in year 51447, which is out of range.

I think, the value is timestamp = 1561360513.087:

```py
dt_object = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1561360513.087)
print(dt_object)
```

You get: "2019-06-24 09:15:13.087000"

Comment: It is a Spark Dataframe where the timestamp variable is in milliseconds. So this corresponds to Monday, June 24, 2019 7:15:13.087 AM.

Comment: OK, so you can divide the timestamp by 1000 to get it in seconds.

Comment: This is a Python solution, not a PySpark solution.